# Why is it not printing the assigned leter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am wanting to change the output but for some reason when i put a letter the assigned letter is completely different

i have tried reassigning, reorganizing almost everything i know and it doesn't work

```
from tkinter import *
import random
window = Tk()
window.title("Enigma Ui")
lbl = Label(window,bg = "#d5ddfc", text='''Welcome''',font=("Helvecta", 12))
lbl.grid(column=20, row=0)
window.geometry('120x90')
window.configure(bg = "#d5ddfc")
def clicked():
    res = "" + txt.get()
    keywords = {'k': 'a',
                '7': 'b',
                'r': 'c',
                '9': 'd',
                'q': 'e',
                '6': 'f',
                'p': 'g',
                '2': 'h',
                'j': 'i',
                '4': 'j',
                'u': 'k',
                '0': 'l',
                'h': 'm',
                '2': 'n',
                '1': 'o',
                '1': 'p',
                'z': 'q',
                'm': 'r',
                '7': 's',
                '3': 't',
                'v': 'u',
                'f': 'v',
                '5': 'w',
                'r': 'x',
                'a': 'y',
                't': 'z'
                }

    new_label_value = res
    for keyword, replacement in keywords.items():
        new_label_value = new_label_value.replace(keyword, replacement)
    lbl.configure(text=new_label_value)
btn = Button(window,text="Decrypt", bg= "#fcfcf3",bd=0, command = clicked)
btn.grid(column=20, row=30)
txt =Entry(window,width=20, bd=0, bg = "white")
txt.grid(column=20,row=35)
window.mainloop()
```

i wan tit so that when i put k7r9q6p2j4u0h2lizm73vf5rat that abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz will come out

Comment: what do you think will happen if you have for example `k` in the original string and you replace it with `a` in the first iteration of the loop and later on in the loop you reach keyword=`a`?

Comment: well i need it to display "a" when the letter k is said os it would replace the k with an a so like this eg: input(k) = "a" = output (a)

Comment: when you use `str.replace()` it will replace `k` with `a` everywhere in the string. Now it will have both original `a` chars and also `a` chars instead of original `k`. Then at the second to last iteration of the loop you will replace all `a` chars currently present (i.e. both original and `k` replacements). it will help to understand what is going on if you print `new_label_value` in each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand why you need to use replace. You have a dictionary that has all of your encrypted characters as keys and all of your unencrypted characters as values to those keys. All you need to do is iterate through a loop of every character in your encrypted string and then use that as the key for your dictionary:

```
from tkinter import *
import random
window = Tk()
window.title("Enigma Ui")

lbl = Label(window,bg = "#d5ddfc", text='''Welcome''',font=("Helvecta", 12))
lbl.grid(column=20, row=0)

window.geometry('120x90')
window.configure(bg = "#d5ddfc")

def clicked():
    new_label_value = ''
    keywords = {'k': 'a',
            '7': 'b',
            'r': 'c',
            '9': 'd',
            'q': 'e',
            '6': 'f',
            'p': 'g',
            '2': 'h',
            'j': 'i',
            '4': 'j',
            'u': 'k',
            '0': 'l',
            'h': 'm',
            '2': 'n',
            'l': 'o',
            'i': 'p',
            'z': 'q',
            'm': 'r',
            '7': 's',
            '3': 't',
            'v': 'u',
            'f': 'v',
            '5': 'w',
            'r': 'x',
            'a': 'y',
            't': 'z'
            }
    for i in txt.get():
        new_label_value = new_label_value + keywords[str(i)]
    lbl.configure(text=new_label_value)

btn = Button(window,text="Decrypt", bg= "#fcfcf3",bd=0, command = clicked)
btn.grid(column=20, row=30)

txt =Entry(window,width=20, bd=0, bg = "white")
txt.grid(column=20,row=35)

window.mainloop()
```

On a side note, the string "k7r9q6p2j4u0h2lizm73vf5rat" doesn't output "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", but does output "asxdefgnijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", this is because you have not declared your dictionary correctly.

You also had two dictionary keys for "l" and none for "i", so I replaced the second instance of "l" with an "i".

Comment: so how would i define it properly as  im quite new to this and i dont really know how to do it any other way

Comment: @HyperStrike1212 How would you define what, sorry?